# Xamarin app (Android) can't access mongodb server in local network from physical device(s)

Tags: android, .net, mongodb, xamarin, local

I'm running a test environment with multiple physical android phones in my local network. In the network i have a MongoDB server I want to access.

I am unable to connect from the apps, though the same code works perfect in a regular console application. I've googled this, but I only find information about localhost, (on which an emulator and server/service is running)

To answer some questions questions:
No, I can't make the IP public and access it from the web.
Yes, I've tried multiple phones.
Yes, I've looked into the app permissions.
No, I can't just use a free online service, because I'm testing how millions of write/read requests will load a system, (so we can judge the cost of a cloud service versus in-house hosting).
Yes, I've tested that it works against online resources (Azure cosmos db).

Comment: Connect the devices to a local wireless AP and use the same IP subnet for the DHCP of the devices as well as the local MongoDB server/instance (static IP I assume...)

Comment: "Unable to connect" - are you getting an exception or error?  Have you ruled out basic networking issue - ie, can you connect to the server from the test device?  Are you sure there are no firewall issues?

Comment: @SushiHangover They are on the same "everything". I checked all IP adresses

Comment: @Jason It returns null, (it just returns a "isNullException", as if it's not locating the host. No firewalls, (as stated a test application on my desktop computer runs the same code snippit with the same libraries and gets the data perfectly. And I can access multiple resources on the server device, (I alsos runs  a mysql server and web server)

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: Are mongodb binding ip correctly set (other that localhost only?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, (stackoverflow went down for maintainance, so I contiued on my own).

Turned out that I was missing a something in my "catch", so it caught the error, and did nothing, giving me the result "{}", because I had some methods calling methods in other classes calling more methods in more classes, there never was an error message.

So working code, (standard connection code from mongodb documentation):

```
public async Task<string> LoginAsync(string name, string password)
    {
        if (!Ready) { Start(); }
        var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
        var filter = builder.Eq("nick", name) & builder.Eq("password", password);

        string output;

        try
        {
            var var1 = await CosmosUsersCollection.Find(filter).FirstAsync();
            output = var1.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // important for uncovering errors
            output = ex.Message;
        }

        return output;
    }
```